# В базу данных не добавлятся строки где есть символ ' (апостроф)

Tags: php, mysql

Запросом в базу пытаюсь занести данные из массива. Но почему-то запросом игнорируются строки, где есть символ ('). Строки с этим символом просто игнорируются. Вот код, которым пытаюсь добавить:

```
 $item_list = file_get_contents(ROOT."/models/file.json");
 $inv = json_decode($item_list, true);




  $api = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  $CONNECT = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die("CONNECTION ERROR !");

       foreach ($inv['items_game']['items'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ( $value['prefab'] == "wearable"){                                       

                        $string = $value['image_inventory'];
                        $link = substr($string,strrpos($string,'/') +1,strlen($string));
                        $item_link = file_get_contents("https://link.com");
                        $item_info = json_decode($item_link, true);

                        mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `itemlist_steam`  VALUES ( '',  $key, '".$value['name']."', '".$item_info['result']['path']."')");

                    }
```

Как заставить этот запрос не игнорировать value['name'], в котором есть ' ?

Comment: _никогда_ не подставляйте данные в текст запроса. Используйте привязываемые значения http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Подумайте, что будет, если кто-нибудь вроде меня попробует написать строку `', ''); DROP TABLE itemlist_steam; --`